# Border of nested table - want none, got one

Tags: html, css, html-table

This one makes me feel stupid. I want to split a certain cell in a table, and I want it to not have a border. The parent table does have a border, which is set in css:

```
table, thead, tbody, th, tr, td, input
 {
     clear: both;
     font-size: 11pt;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
 }
table, thead, tbody, th, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

In order to split the desired cell, I create a nested table with inline style set to border:0 like this (here shown surrounding parent table with only affected th and value td within:

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: linen">
        <th>
            <table style="table-layout: fixed; border: 0">
                <tr style="border: 0">
                    <th style="text-align: center;border: 0">
                        <label>NDA</label>
                    </th>
                    <th style="text-align: center;border: 0">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Mailshot, "Mailshot")
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: linen">
        <td>
            <table style="border: 0">
                <tr style="border: 0">
                    <td style="text-align: center; border: 0;width: 50%">
                        <input type="checkbox" style="border: none" value="@Model.NdaSigned" name="NdaSigned" id="NdaSigned"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center; border: 0;width: 50%">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="@Model.Mailshot" name="Mailshot" id="Mailshot"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I have already tried about everything I could think of to make sure the nested table does NOT have a border. (P.S: border:none has the same non-effect).

Yet, this is what it looks like:

[image]

I wouldn't terribly mind a 1px vertical border in the middle but I certainly do NOT want a surrounding border within the cell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of a nested table, isn't it way more easy to fill the cell with 2 div's each 50% width?

Comment: Different approach. I like to be consistent and treat cells like cells. The answer below sounds very plausible.

Comment: By the way, I wonder who votes to close this as off topic. It is a very distinct problem that is reproduced by the code in the post, so what more could you want?

Comment: I also wondered who downvoted this. I described my problem clearly, included code, searched before to avoid a duplicate... Probably an HTML or CSS guru who felt offended by the simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables always have tbodies, even if you don't write `<tbody>` explicitly. So each of the inner tables has a tbody with a border of `1px solid black` as per your css.

Solutions are to either put `<tbody style="border:0">` in the inner tables, or to remove the `tbody` selector from the css. (The latter would be preferred, since you don't actually need to style tbodies in the first place except in very specialised circumstances.)

Comment: Removing tbody from CSS didn't work for whatever reason (maybe cache), but <tbody style="border:0"> did it. I knew it had to be some simple minuteness. Thanks.

Comment: @LocEngineer Strange. You did remove it from the second style block in the css, right, not just the first?

Comment: Removed it from both actually. Will retry later with a cleared browser cache.

Comment: Herewith confirmed: after I cleared browser cache and rebuilt solution, removing tbody from css did the job just as well. +1